# ajaxStart&ajaxStop: how to log requested url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a single page application where all the subpages are loaded using jQuery.load() or .Ajax() functions.

I have set up ajaxStart() and ajaxStop to display an animation while performing the request and it is working fine. 
The code I use is the following:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (){
    //$('.contenitore').toggle('fast');
    $('#darkLayer').show();
    document.title = 'sto elaborando...';
    resizeDiv();
}).ajaxStop(function (){
    //$('.contenitore').toggle('fast');
    $('#darkLayer').hide();
    document.title = 'J.E.N.I.U.S.';
    resizeDiv();
});
```

I'd like to be able to create a log of what the user does and so I'd like to store in a mysql log what the user has done. **Does anyone know how to pass to ajaxStart and ajaxStop the url passed to the .load() or .ajax() function?**
This way I will have a single point where to use the function that will log the data (user, when, what).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

```
$.ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  console.log(settings.url);
});
```

or You can define beforeSend handler globally:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
     console.log(settings.url);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks. I was looking on load and ajax and didn't think about ajaxComplete! :) time to go on holidays for a while I suppose! :)